# Manually changing URL hash does not navigate to section in Next.js

Tags: url, next.js, scroll, anchor

I am working on a Next.js project and I'm trying to navigate to a specific section that has `id='section'` on a page using the URL hash.

When I click on a link with `href='#section'`, it correctly scrolls to the desired section.

However, when I manually change the hash in the URL to "www.example.com#section", it doesn't navigate to the section.

Is there a way to fix it without using useRouter() ?

EDIT:

I noticed that sometimes it works, sometimes not.

For exemple when I start with the page "www.example.com" then add to it "#section", it indeed scrolls to the corresponding section.

But when I directly enter "www.example.com#section" it doesn't.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by utilizing JavaScript's scrollIntoView() method within useEffect hook. Add a script to your page that listens for changes in the URL hash and scrolls to the corresponding section.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const MyPage = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleHashChange = () => {
      const { hash } = window.location
      if (hash) {
        const targetElement = document.querySelector(hash)
        if (targetElement) {
          targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
        }
      }
    }

    handleHashChange() // Scroll to section on initial load

    // Listen for hash changes and scroll to the section
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange)

    return () => {
      // Clean up event listener
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <section id="section">
        {/* Content of the section */}
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}
```